# Is there any way to get product with his last price in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get product with his last *price* (price with last `created_at`)

I have :

`product` table:

```
id, name,created_at, updated_at
```

`product_prices` table:

```
id, product_id, price, created_at, updated_at
```

In `Product` model :

```php
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product_price' , 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

In `Product_price` model:

```php
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product' ,  'product_id');
}
```

on `ProductController.php`:

```php
public function GetALlProducts()
{

    $products = new Product;
    $products = $products->with('prices');

    $products = $products->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

I received all products with all their prices and i don't want this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another relationship to your `Product` model, i.e.:

```php
public function last_price()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product_price')->latest();
}
```

Then you can *eager load* the `last_price` with your `$products`, i.e.:

```php
$products = Product::with('last_price')->get();
```